# Authorization via Controller helper: Method authorize() does not exists - Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I defined `PostPolicy.php` to handle who can access actions.
I'm trying to handle PUT request to update a Post, but its seems not working correctly.

```
namespace App\Policies;

use App\Models\Users;
use App\Models\Posts;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\HandlesAuthorization;

class PostPolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    public function view(Users $user, Posts $posts)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function create(Users $user)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function update(Users $user, Posts $posts)
    {
        return true; //$user->id === $posts->user_id;
    }

    public function delete(Users $user, Posts $posts)
    {
        return $user->id === $posts->user_id;
    }
}
```

I registered this policy in `AuthServiceProvider.php`

```
protected $policies = [
    'App\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
    App\Models\Posts::class => App\Policies\PostPolicy::class,
];
```

My route:

```
Route::put('post/update/{id}', 'CMS\PostController@update');
```

Last, here is my controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\CMS;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;
use App\Models\Posts as PostModel;
use LRedis;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PostController extends BaseController
{
    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    public function update (Request $request, PostModel $postModel) {
        $this->authorize('update', $postModel);

    }

    public function subcribe () {
    }
}
```

When I submit form, I got error `Method [authorize] does not exist on [App\Http\Controllers\CMS\PostController].`

I'm making my demo follow [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authorization#via-controller-helpers).

What are my wrongs? Am i missing any in progress?

Comment: yes you are missing something .. your controller doesn't have those methods ... take a look at the controller you are supposed to extend in your application `App\Http\Controllers\Controller` ... just aliasing things in the top of your file, doesn't do anything by itself

Answer (score 7):

The `authorize` method is made available by the `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests` trait.

You can either directly add this trait to your controller, or you can have your controller extend the default controller that ships with Laravel (`App\Http\Controllers\Controller`), as it already has this trait (as well as `DispatchesJobs` and `ValidatesRequests`).

Comment: Yap, its my missing. `authorize()` method worked. But I got error `This action is unauthorized`, although method `update()` in `PostPolicy` already return `true`

Comment: FYI, as of right now, the Laravel man page on authorization makes no mention of this trait.

Comment: @JayBienvenu It doesn't mention the trait, but it does say "Laravel provides a helpful authorize method to any of your controllers which extend the App\Http\Controllers\Controller base class." (https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/authorization#via-controller-helpers) If you look at that base class, you will see that it uses the mentioned trait.

Comment: Yeah, and that indication should be in the man page itself; the developer shouldn't have to dig through class code to find it.

Comment: @JayBienvenu You can always make a PR to the docs to add it. But, there has to be a line drawn somewhere as to what should be in the docs. If you add too many details, the docs become too large, and that gets in the way of getting the general information across.

Answer (score 1):

The generated controller extends the default `Illuminate\Routing\Controller` not the usual `App\Http\Controllers\Controller` as in a fresh Laravel installation.

To be able to use authorization related methods you have to use the `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests` trait in your class:

```
<?php
namespace Module\Posts\Http\Controllers;

// Add this use statement
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;

class PostController extends Controller
{
    use AuthorizesRequests;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->authorizeResource(Post::class, 'post');
    }

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should declare all policies in App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider.php file on your project file. In this case, you have to declare PostPolicy like this:

in the AuthServiceProvider.php:

```
protected $policies = [
    // 'App\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
        Post::class => PostPolicy::class,
];
```

You can find more information via checking official documentation laravel [enter link description here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authorization)